# Add events using Extension methods

Tags: c#, events, extension-methods

I have found several posts about Raising events with an extension method, however my question is a bit different:

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IStateMachine 
{
    void SetState(IState NewState);
    IState GetState();
}
```

Using this interface I can create an extension method like follows:

```
public static void ChangeState(this IStateMachine StateMachine, IState NewState) 
{
    StateMachine.GetState().Exit();
    StateMachine.SetState(NewState);
    StateMachine.GetState().Enter();
}
```

What I really want is that there will be events that need to be fired, e.g.: a `statechange-event`.

However I don't want the `StatechangeEvent` to be a part of the `IStateMachine` interface, but it seems that that's the only way. I have several classes that implement `IStateMachine`, and therefore I have to redo the same code every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, there are only extension methods. No extension properties or events.

You will have to declare the event on the interface.
To avoid the need to write the same event code over and over, you can create a base class.

Another possibility would be to "manually" implement the [Publish-Subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe) pattern. That's what events in C# are.

You can add the extension methods `Subscribe` and `Unsubscribe` to `IStateMachine`.

They would use a possibly static class `StateMachineSubscribers` which also exposes the `Subscribe` and `Unsubscribe` methods. Additionally, it exposes a `Raise` method used by your `ChangeState` extension method.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that. I have different type of classs that can all be a IStateMachine. When I am making a base abstract class I am getting problems with multiple inheritance.

Comment: @avanwieringen: In that case implementing pub/sub on the interface via extension methods seems to be the better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The event  with its corresponding delegate can be a part of a *concrete class* that *implements* that `IStateMachine` interface. So if you call `SetState`, on interface, its *concrete* implementaion of some *concrete* class is called, which inside of it raises an event you want.